# Hibernate Query Not Projecting Correctly in One To Many

Tags: hibernate, criteria, one-to-many

I am doing a query where I need to get a user back, that also has UserConnectors populated with it.  My Query keeps bringing back two results instead of one for a single ID.  It should be one result, but I think the UserConnector join since the User has two of them, is creating two Users in the result, one for each User Connector.

Tables

User: ID NAME
UserConnector: ID, USERID, DATE

User.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
     public Set<UserConnector> getUserConnectors() {
        return this.userConnectors;
     }

    /**
     * Set the list of Connectors
     */
     public void setUserConnectors(Set<UserConnector> userConnectors) {
        this.userConnectors = userConnectors;
     }
```

UserConnector.java

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "USERID")
public User getUser() {
    return this.user;
}

/**
 * set users
 */
public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

Query

```
Criteria criteria = userRepository.getCritieria();

            criteria.createAlias("userConnectors", "uc", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);

            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", request.getId()));
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("enabled", new Long("1")));
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("uc.active", new Long("1")));

            List<User> list = userRepository.findByCriteria(criteria);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
  List users = session.createCriteria(User.class)
  .add( Restrictions.idEq(request.getId()))
  .add( Restrictions.eq("enabled", new Long("1")))
  .createCriteria("userConnectors")
      .add( Restrictions.like("active", new Long("1")) )
  .list();
```

Comment: Same thing:


List<User> list = userRepository.getCritieria()
     .add( Restrictions.idEq(request.getId()))
     .add( Restrictions.eq("enabled", new Long("1")))
     .createCriteria("userConnectors")
         .add( Restrictions.like("active", new Long("1")) )
     .list();

Answer (score 0):

As well as with HQL, for `Criteria` with joins you need to trigger distinct projection manually:

```
 criteria.setResultTransformer(DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
```

Comment: Getting error nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE.  You did give me an idea though, where I tried criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ROOT_ENTITY), but it still gave me same result.